# Detect ipad with Rest Request

Tags: java, http, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am using Rest Webservices with jersey,
so I need to detect User agent type.

if I use Servlet I may detect like this

```
public boolean isMobile(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception { 
String user_agent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
```

but I am using Jersey so I can not parse HttpRequest ,
Is there any way to detect user agent HTTP header with jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

```
@POST
@Path("/msisdn")
public Response verify(@Context HttpHeaders headers, MsisdnVerifyRequestBean reqBean) {
    if (personDao == null) {
        return Response.status(506).entity("DI error").build();
    }
    String userAgent = headers.getRequestHeader("user-agent").get(0);
    if(userAgent.contains("ipad")){
    reqBean.setType(2);
    }
```